# Swapping light fixtures

Tags: light-fixture

I have two white wires and one black wire in a metal ceiling box.

When I hook up new fixture  I connect whites together and blacks together and bare ground from new fixture to the box but light doesn't work.

The light does work however if I UN-hook the black wires and take black wire from fixture and touch it to the bare ground wire I have connected to the box.

What do I do to make this right?

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] your post to include some pictures of the wiring, that will help us help you. While you're waiting for an answer, you should also take the [tour] and read the [help] to familiarize yourself with how this site differs from others you may have visited.

Comment: Please: at your level of knowledge of electricity,  **STOP RIGHT NOW** before you hurt yourself.   The wiring at each (if more than one) switch is equally important, as is the way the previous fixture was wired into the bos.

Comment: install it the same way as the light before was connected. If you don't know how that was, hire someone who can safely figure it out.

Comment: I agree with the other comments, You do not have the knowledge to proceed safely. ALSO, **n** is not a word, it is not a substitute for the word "**and**". I fixed it for you.

Comment: I fully agree with Carl. If it worked when you connected a black wire to a ground wire, you have things badly (and dangerously) mis-wired. You are very close to literally killing yourself! Please just stop!